# Installation hangs during "detect network hardware"

Tags: thinkpad, debian-wheezy

I try to install Debian Wheezy beta 1 using the netinstall image on a Lenovo W510 with this network hardware

```
Intel Corporation 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection
Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6200
```

and the setup hangs by "detect network hardware". I tried to install the non-free image firmware-wheezy-DI-b1-amd64-netinst too -> same problem. I tried wired and wireless connection.

Does anybody know why or if and how I had to add a network driver during the setup process?